How to decrease the range of the for loop in python?
In this question I wanted to find min(m+k) such that mCk =n, I wrote a code to brute force for my sequence, The problem was that my code isn't fast enough so I want to decrease the length of the for loop as k progress
import math
print("the input is the maximum number $n$ to check for i.e for all u between 1, n the code gives the min m+k suck that mCk =n , the output is in the for of $(n , min (m+k : mCk=n)) $")
u=int(input())
for n in range (2,u+1):
    C=[]
    stop=1
    l=0
    for m in range (1, n+1):
        s=0
        if stop==-1:
            break
        for k in range(1, math.floor(m/2)+1-l):
            if math.comb(m,k)>n:
                l=l+1
                break
            if math.comb(m,k)==n:
                C.insert(s,m+k )
                s=s+1
                if min(C)<n+1:
                    stop=-1
                    break                      
    print(f"({n},{min(C)}), ")                               


These are the first initial values that the code gives:
( 2, 3),
( 3, 4),
( 4, 5),
( 5, 6),
( 6, 6),
( 7, 8),
( 8, 9),
( 9, 10),
( 10, 7),
( 11, 12),
( 12, 13),
( 13, 14),
( 14, 15),
( 15, 8),
( 16, 17),
( 17, 18),
( 18, 19),
( 19, 20),
( 20, 9),
( 21, 9),
( 22, 23),
( 23, 24),
( 24, 25),
( 25, 26),
( 26, 27),
( 27, 28),
( 28, 10),
( 29, 30),
( 30, 31),
( 31, 32),
( 32, 33),
( 33, 34),
( 34, 35),
( 35, 10)

The problem is writing something like this :
k=0
for i in range (0,100-k+1):
    if i%2==0
        k=k+1

doesn't decrease the length of the range , which something I need to do with my code
I tried to search for solutions to this problem but I only found unrelated stack overflow questions.

@SiHa But I don't want to exist the loop, I want to decrease the end value based on my if condition so that code take less time to run. Is there is other solutions to this problem?

You can use a while loop (while i < 100 - k + 1) don't forget to set i to 0 before entering the loop and update i inside the loop.

What exactly is the code supposed to do? What's the input, what's the output?

What is "fast enough"?

@nocomment You can read the MO question for more information (because writing mathematics without latex is painful) anyways the input is the  maximum number $n$ to check for i.e for all s between 1, n the code gives the min m+k suck that mCk =n

Yeah I already read the MO question. That "input is max ..., output is all ..." is what I was looking for. Would better be in the question's description as well, perhaps with an example, like the output for input 10.

@nocomment With that being said do you have an idea how to make this code faster ?

Maybe. But again, what's "fast enough"? I tried input 1000, took less than a second.

@nocomment Try bigger than 10000 , 10,000 take a whole minute anything larger than that isn't gonna work, I want up to 100,000 or 1,000,000 because I am interested more in  $a_n < n+1$ which doesn't appear very often so I need more numbers

I suggest to ask that as another question then. But with the code changed so that you have a function that takes the upper limit as argument and returns a list of the pairs. That makes it easy to compare the outputs and times of different implementations. Oh and use C.append(m+k), no s needed.

Ok I can do 1,000,000 in less than a second now. With about half as much code.

@nocomment How ?

Post the question, then I can post it as an answer :-)

@nocomment I can't post a question here rn I have to wait 2 days to ask again :(

Ah, annoying. Does that ban apply to the staging ground as well?

@nocomment You can post your answer on MSE or MO btw.

They seem to ask how to find a single a_n, not all up to some limit. Of course from the latter you can extract the former, but I suspect it's not a good way. Also, they ask with 2 < k < r-2, so they seem broken.

My program is pretty much the same as what Peter just posted.

You have:
k=0
for i in range (0,100-k+1):
    if i%2==0
        k=k+1

Ultimately you cannot use the range function. Since k is 0 initially, your range function could have been simplified to range(0, 101). In your loop's body you have k=k+1. It appears your intention is to reduce the ending value of your range by 1. So we have:
i = 0
max_i = 101
while i < max_i:
    print(i)  # For demo purposes
    if i % 2 == 0:
        max_i -= 1  # Reduce max_i
    i += 1  # Increment i for next iteration

This will print out 0, 1, 2, ... 66

The comment by @Sieha is correct. The loops length cannot be changed.
A while loop seems more appropriate.
Another option is to use the continue keyword instead of break.
continue will ignore the rest of the loop for that iteration.
for i in range(5):
    print(f"iteration {i}")
    if i>1:
      continue
    print("skipped when i>i")

will output
iteration 0
skipped when i>2
iteration 1
skipped when i>2
iteration 2
iteration 3

iteration 4
